# Table with width assignment

Tags: tables, width

I am trying to create a matrix in texmaker when using the wizard-->quick tabular i get a table, but I want to have equal spacing between the columns , so at the option i choose fixed column width when i see the code I noticed that

```
%\usepackage{array} is required
```

so i place it the pre-amble and hit compile but it doesnot allow me to compile it and goes into a never ending loop

```
\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
• & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{location} \\ 
\hline 
• & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\hline 
Average & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
Average measure& • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
A & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
B & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
C & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
D & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
E & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Is there a way to set a designated width to the code used above, with out the use of packages ?

Comment: Did you type real bullets in your code?

Comment: @Bernard no i did not, I used the wizard to create the table

Comment: Can you copy the *.log into your question or publish it somewhere? Your example runs without any hiccup here on Windows 7 / texlive 2014.

Comment: @KeksDose the example is the one that runs, but when i try to insert p{} for width then i go into an infinite loop and cannot do anything on texmaker, not even copy. The question is if there is a command to set width ?

Comment: It compiles fine with — note I used the article class as the elsevier package is not installed on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools, array, textcomp}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|p{2cm}}|p{2cm}|}
\hline 
• & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{location} \\ 
\hline 
• & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\hline 
Average & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
Average measure& • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
A & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
B & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
C & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
D & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
E & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

By the way: the log-file resides in the same folder than you document. Just go there and open it with an editor.

Comment: thank you , yes something like that, i will fitted to the proper width. I was curious on why the wizard didnt work correctly but i think now i will create them in this fashion. Thank you very much